# Selenium is not getting elements

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I want to fetch some elements but it is throwing error "". My java code is -

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("New User")));
driver.findElement(By.name("New User")).click();
```

And HTML code is like bellow hierarchy.

```
/html/frameset/frame/html/body/table/tr/td/New User
```

I am using internet explorer 8 so unable to find xpath there fore i have not tied by xpath method.

Comment: `but it is throwing error `..what error?

Comment: Please add more info... like the relevant HTML, more of what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `iframe` which you have to switch to:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // 0 - means, switch to the first frame

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("New User"))).click();
```

Comment: Just a refinement. [visibilityOfElementLocated](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns the WebElement it is waiting for, thus the explicit findElement is redundant: `WebElement newUserLink = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("New User"))); newUserLink.click()`

Comment: @alb-i986 yeah, sure, though that was not the point of the answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works but how i know frame(0) or frame(1). what are these 0 and 1

Comment: @Shik 0 - is the first, 1 is the second. You can also use a name or an id, or a `WebElement` instead of an index.

Comment: Now i am searching for another frame but it give error "Unable to find element with name == DetailFrame " my code is driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("DetailFrame")));

Comment: The frame i want to search is inside another frame. I can get outer frame but how can i get inner frame . Out frame is "rightFrame" and inner frame is "DetailFrame". Please help